# Cocoapods: When using "use_frameworks!", how do I exclude a single pod?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mopub

A certain pod (mopub-ios-sdk) doesn't compile with the "use_frameworks!" option.

It's possible to edit two #import statements in the pod and make it compile, but I'd prefer to not do that.

Is there a way to make one specific pod *not* compile into a framework, but into a dynamic library instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, CocoaPods supports integrating all dependencies as frameworks, or all as static libraries.